# How to show bottom sheet on map in flutter mobile application?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, bottom-sheet

I see a lot of tutorials for implementing bottom sheet in my flutter application, but i am facing problem in implementing that, all of them showing bottom sheet after onPressed/onTap and i do not want that. I had implemented google map in my application but now i want to show persistent bottom sheet after i got response from API on map screen and color of that bottom sheet must be transparent so that map can be visible through bottom sheet.

**Can you share some code that how can i show bottomsheet without onpressed on google map screen in flutter mobile application?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use a stack widget and visibility widgets to show that.
here is some minimalist code
`bool _isVisible=false;`

```
//after you get a response  fro your api you set state of `_isVisible` to `true/!_isVisible.`
    Stack....

    Positioned(bottom:10,left:0 
    child: Visibility(visible:!_isVisible,
     child Container(color:Colors.Transparent,
    child:Center(child:Text("your data here")))),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

after getting your data :

```
return showModalBottomSheet(

        isDismissible: false,

        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: ?,
          ),
        ),
      );
```